# How to include symbols in matplotlib title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to include symbols in the matplotlib title but the following code doesn't work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N_combs=10
t1 = np.random.randint(100, size=(N_combs,2))
g1=np.random.randint(100, size=(N_combs,2))
plt.plot(range(100), np.random.randn(100, N_combs))    
plt.title([rf'$\tau_c1={x} \tau_c2={y} \Delta G_{{01}}={i} \Delta G_{{01}}={j}$' for x,y in t1[0] for i,j in g1[0]])
```

Error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-972-589f95b4b1cf>", line 8, in <module>
    plt.title([rf'$\tau_c1={x} \tau_c2={y} \Delta G_{{01}}={i} \Delta G_{{01}}={j}$' for x,y in t1[0] for i,j in g1[0]])

  File "<ipython-input-972-589f95b4b1cf>", line 8, in <listcomp>
    plt.title([rf'$\tau_c1={x} \tau_c2={y} \Delta G_{{01}}={i} \Delta G_{{01}}={j}$' for x,y in t1[0] for i,j in g1[0]])

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int32 object
```

on the contrary, if I use plt.legend, it works.

Comment: You might to replace `t1[0]`and `g1[0]` with `t1` and `g1`. It cannot unpack non-iterable int object indeed, because it expect 2-length variables in your case which is not right.

Comment: Also, your title bust be a string, not array so you need to use `'\n'.join(<your list>)` instead

Comment: Could you please expand on your second point ? I tried the following but didnt work- plt.title('\n'.join([rf'$\tau_c1={x} \tau_c2={y} \Delta G_{{01}}={i} \Delta G_{{01}}={j}$' for x,y in t1[0] for i,j in g1[0]]))

Comment: `plt.title('\n'.join([rf'$\tau_c1={x} \tau_c2={y} \Delta G_{{01}}={i} \Delta G_{{01}}={j}$' for x,y in t1 for i,j in g1]))` works for me. I also add `plt.show()` at the end of my script.

Comment: What is more, your size of title is enormously large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine each Latex string with a formatting function.

```
(plt.title(r'$\tau_c1=$'+'{}'.format(t1[0][0])
   +r'$\tau_c2=$'+'{}'.format(t1[0][1])
   +r'$\Delta G_{{01}}=$'+'{}'.format(g1[0][1])
   +r'$\Delta G_{{01}}=$'+'{}'.format(g1[0][1]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! But why is it not able to print the tau symbol corresponding to \tau_c2 ?

Comment: I found the cause. Each of them had to have an `r` in the head.